# Логический и объектно-ориентированный язык программирования

Tags: java, ооп, логика, prolog

Долго кодил на java, страстно любя его ООП. Потом увидел prolog и тогда влюбился в логическое программирования. Теперь захотелось совместить.

**Вопрос:** есть ли такой замечательный язык, который бы совмещал обе парадигмы?

**P. S.** По моему такой язык был бы идеален для написания стратегий/мини искусственного интеллекта.

**P. P. S.** только что осознал, что хочу Джаву, в которую впихнули логическое. Хотя это в идеале.

Comment: @alexlz таких как оз полно, хочется что то более направленное только на ооп и лп без фп

Comment: а что должен уметь язык, что бы быть "логическим"? ответ "как пролог" не подходит.

А мне к примеру java не нравиться - там нет встроенного map/reduce и возможности делать ссылки на функции (в 8 вроде появилось).

Перл и хаскель пробовали?

Comment: Почему ответ "как пролог не подходит"? Я хочу как пролог)

А есть языки где есть встроенный map/reduce? Не могу себе представить. Про ссылки: это == лямбды? Да, они есть в java 8

В перле мало ооп :), а хаскел - жуткая функциональщина (имхо)

Comment: Ну логическое - это же все не предикатах. Описываете интерфейс Predicate и вперед. Что вам еще нужно? :)

Comment: Тяжеловато будет это реализовать. Писать много, возни много. Плюс отсутствие синтаксического сахара для предикатах. Хотя можно попробовать)

Comment: Если хочется как пролог - используйте пролог. Почему не подходит ответ "как пролог"? потому что он не говорит, что именно нравиться.

лямбды - это не совсем ссылки. Классическая задача, решаемая в многих языках, но сложно решаемая в java - это сделать map, ключами которого были бы слова, а значениями - ссылки на функции. В java 6 приходиться делать пачку if-else if- else.

В перл достаточно объектости, хаскель - красив. Но нужно хорошо попробовать его. 


Языки со встроенным map/reduce - хаскель, perl. В с++ - в базовой поставке.

Можно и на плюсах писать красивый функциональный код.

Comment: @danpetruk что Вам такого плохого сделало функциональное программирование/программисты, что одно наличие ФП уже делает язык некошерным? 

И, как я понимаю, в Вашем чёрном списке не только python, scala, lisp'ы и f#, но и javascript, и perl, да и c# вроде. Тяжко Вам.

Ну а что касается вашего вопрос -- гугл в помощь. https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=object-oriented+prolog&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: @alexlz

> haskell -- не язык логического программирования (т.е. сам уравнения не решает). 

Это Вам к wolframalpha.com - он решает.

> что одно наличие ФП уже делает язык некошерным

не все могут с наскока осилить ФП. По моему мнению ФП языки и обычные (С++/Java) это как русский и арабский. То есть, нужно немного сломать мозг.

Comment: @KoVadim 

Императивное программирование -- программист задаёт последовательность действий, которые следует выполнить, чтобы получился нужный результат.

ФП -- программист задаёт выражение (элементами первого порядка которого могут быть и функции), кот. вычисляет результат.

ЛП -- программист задаёт систему логических уравнений, которые система должна решить, чтобы получить результат.

Насчёт сломать мозг -- вспомните, как Вы учились программировать вычисление факториала. Из формулы n! = n*(n-1)! Надо было сломать мозг. Мозг был сломан. В ФП нужно восстановить исходное состояние. Это непросто

Comment: Для меня рекурсивное вычисление факториала было абсолютно нормальным и понятным. И мозг не ломал.

В ФП подобное (рекурсия) используется на каждом шаге, так что после факториала ничего не нужно восстанавливать.

Как по мне, то, судя с определения ФП и ЛП - ЛП частный случай ФП.

Comment: @KoVadim То, что для Вас рекуррентные вычисления абсолютно нормальны и понятны -- это очень хорошо. Ну а

     судя с определения ФП и ЛП - ЛП частный случай ФП.

-- это уже странное утверждение. Когда Вы пишете выражение в ФП, которое нужно вычислить, Вы всегда знаете, что Вы хотите получить. В ЛП несколько иначе. Если Вы связали уравнениями два параметра (или три, или больше) -- Вы не обязаны знать при кодировании, какой параметр будет неизвестным. Это можно видеть и в прологе, но очень красочно изображено в Programming with Narrowing S. Antoy

Comment: Логическое программирование по сути умерло, дальше игрушечных задач пролог и Ко не пошли. С ним стоит поиграться, но в ближайшие 15 лет вы вряд ли сможете найти работу в этой области.

Comment: @VladD а ии? Алгоритмы-стратегии? Мне кажется писать игрушки на нём самое-то (за исключением движка)

Comment: @alexlz oz -о подобные: alice, mozart и т.д.

Comment: @VladD Насчёт перспектив трудоустройства на 15 лет сейчас что-то предсказывать рисково -- кризис потихоньку нарастает. Может накрыть не только пролог.

Я не сторонник ЛП, но наличие множества языков (в т.ч. диалектов пролога) свидетельствует, что оно всё-таки живо. Кстати, выведение типов (в т.ч. Хиндли-Милнера) в современных языках -- это как раз ЛП. А вакансии -- видимо так и есть. Но "игрушка" -- нет.

@danpetruk Т.е. мультипарадигменный oz плох, а м.-п. Scala хорош, даже без ЛП. И, кстати, в ряду alice (ЛП? ФП?), mpzart -- кто такой mozart? (с языком oz) (В репозитории ubuntu alice -- нет

Comment: @danpetruk, Prolog и AI (он же ИИ). Помните японский проект компьютеров 5-го поколения в конце 80-х? И где он сейчас?


@VladD, прав. Все подобные штуки даже на современном уровне железа -- это просто игрушки. Они не могут "перемалывать" достаточные для практических целей массивы данных.

Comment: А как же ИИ Watson от IBM? Там ведь как С++, так и Prolog с Java..
Или Clarissa, что NASA на МКС отправила?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Почему бы не использовать реализации Prolog под Java?

- [GNU Prolog Java](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnuprologjava/)
- [JIProlog](http://www.jiprolog.com/)
- [Tuprolog](http://alice.unibo.it/xwiki/bin/view/Tuprolog/)

Comment: @avp а ведь когда-то перл сильно обгонял питон по популярности. И питоновцы при каждом удобном и неудобном случае поминали MS Merchant Server, изначально написанный на питоне. Но это было в прошлом веке.

А ООП, как мне кажется, пришлась очень впору для оправдания обильного перекармливания отрасли финансами. Пример процесса от Хазина -- yahoo, отношение капитализации к прибыли около 1000 в 90е (т.е. купив акцию, получишь дивиденды на сумму покупки за 1000 лет). Но это уже совсем другая история.

Comment: @alexlz (кончился лимит в той ветке, пишу здесь). Scala - cи синтаксис, поддержка java библиотек + исполняется в jvm, комьюнити, 95% языка - ооп

Comment: @danpetruk про Scala -- откуда цитата? И всё-таки, как же с "языком mozart" и alice?

Comment: @danpetruk, про пятое поколение [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). Вообще гугл на

    компьютеры пятого поколения япония

дает много ссылок (думаю, на  аналогичный English запрос их будет еще больше).

И вот еще интересная статья в тему: [Языки программирования через сто лет](http://old.computerra.ru/hitech/35042/).

Comment: @avp Кто его знает, что будет через сто лет? В 2003 Грэм выражал сомнение в распространении параллелизма, чуть позже электроника упёрлась в барьер и ситуация изменилась, в будущем, возможно, барьер будет каким-то образом преодолён или обойдён...

Comment: @alexlz, и в самом деле, вдруг за 100 лет Homo Sapiens резко поумнеют.

А Грэм-то пишет, что язык программирования должен быть простым.

Comment: @avp имхо, если бы это пятое поколение было бы в 2010ы, то оно бы имело хороший успех. Как ibm watson. 

Что же про статью. Имхо, видно он в каком-то своем мире живёт. У него и ооп запутанное, и java гибнущая и параллелизм дохнет 

Про homo sapiens. А почему поумнеют? По идее сейчас должен пойти самый самый гиперболический рост ума из за новых возможностей обучения. Если бы не кислород! Одна из важнейших частей для работы мозга. Которой сейчас не хватает. Когда я начал пить кислородные коктейли, некоторые показатели моего мозга взлетели почти в 2 раза. Но вряд ли его начнёт пить основная масс

Comment: @alexlz http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_(programming_language) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozart_Programming_System

Про какую цитату вы говорите я не понял.

Comment: @danpetruk Цитату? 

     Scala - cи синтаксис, поддержка java библиотек + исполняется в jvm, комьюнити, 95% языка - ооп

Откуда дровишки? Далее

     Что же про статью. Имхо, видно он в каком-то своем мире живёт. У него и ооп запутанное, и java гибнущая и параллелизм дохнет 

А Форбс-то и не знает! ((c) tv-реклама). https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=paul+graham+forbes&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 Тут (не помню кто) написали, что "Y Combinator" -- одни гики, но тем не менее эта фирма ещё не разорилась. Но Грэм, он конечно, в каком-то своём мире живёт.

Comment: @danpetruk цитата из головы

Answer (score 7):

[@danpetruk](/users/8694/danpetruk), а Вам не кажется, что смешивать все (пусть некоторые) парадигмы в одном языке это не очень хорошо.

Если взглянуть на историю программирования, то можно обнаружить, что языки, в которые пытались впихнуть всего и побольше были (например PL/I, algol-68, да та же ada), но по сути умерли.

Вероятно наиболее правильным решением является написание разных частей системы (большой программы) на разных языках. Каждую часть на том, который лучше для этого подходит. Причем, можно попытаться построить реально распределенную систему. А самый сложный тут вопрос -- это связь между ними.

Comment: @avp а что, ada умер? И когда? Ариан он вроде взрывал, а вот что сам умер -- я не читал.

Кстати, первый международно стандартизованный язык ООП.

Comment: @alexlz, [восхищаюсь Вашей эрудицией!](http://www.ci.ru/inform11_97/vzrv.htm) (это оно?)

--

По поводу кончины. Не уверен, что [это](http://www.ohloh.net/languages/compare?measure=commits&percent=true&l0=ada&l1=c&l2=cpp&l3=java&l4=php&l5=-1&commit=Update) истина, но хоть какие-то цифры.

Ну, прямо в стане бывшего потенциального противника, уверен, ситуация в корне другая. 

--

Кстати, много ли здесь людей, написавших хоть пару строк на Аде? Я не писал. Только один из моих знакомых, лет  25 назад, немного поигрался, а потом плевался. Сказал, язык не для *написания*, а для *описания* ПО.

Comment: @avp ну не настолько подробно. Мне уже трудно вспомнить, а в гугле я не нашёл такого места, но почему-то мне казалось, что вопрос обсуждался в comp.lang.ada в начале века (повторяю, гугл такого не нашёл). И причиной называли то, что программу взяли с Ариан4, но некоторые константы были в коде. А движки на Ариан5 мощнее. Но откуда это -- вспомнить не могу.

А нвсчёт использования -- так загляните в эту группу.

Ещё насчёт "25 лет назад". Было два стандарта, старый (ada83) и новый (ada95, если ещё новее не появилось). У сертификатов на трансляторы ada83 срок годности вышел ещё в прошлом веке.

Comment: @alexlz, в какую группу заглянуть?

Что пентагоновский проект - я знаю. Думаю в Honeywell (и куче других фирм) на ней и сейчас пишут.

Причем тут стандарты разных лет на компиляторы -- не понял. Суть языка и его окружения не изменилась. Да, сейчас в аду добавили ООП (если честно, то подробностями не имнтересовался).

--

По поводу живой язык или нет, то мне так кажется. Если язык активно используется все новыми и новыми программистами, то он жив. 

А если на нем пишут 3-5 лет "старшие лейтенанты" после оплаченного универа, то скорее мертв.

Comment: @avp ньюсгруппа comp.lang.ada https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.lang.ada

По поводу сертификатов. Сейчас уже не помню, как оно называется, но компиляторы ada сертифицировались. Т.е. должны были пройти набор тестов на соответствие стандарту. Прошёл -- получи сертификат. Для ada83 срок действия кончался толи в 1998, толи в 1999 -- не помню.

С ada95 несколько иначе -- есть ядро и есть набор дополнений -- annex'ов. Как оно сертифицируется -- что и знал, то забыл. Насчёт использования -- не знаю, смотрите сами. По траффику группы.

Comment: Scala, C#, perl... Все трое мультипарадигменные. И живут

Comment: @avp насчёт смешения парадигм. Вроде Степанов что-то критическое высказывал толи в адрес ООП вообще, толи в адрес ООП в Си++ (ссылки у меня нет).

Comment: @alexlz, [есть такая ссылка](http://blogerator.ru/page/oop_why-objects-have-failed)

    "Я уверен, что ООП методологически неверна. Она начинает с построения классов. Это как если бы математики начинали бы с аксиом.  Но реально никто не начинает с аксиом, все начинают с доказательств. Только когда найден набор подходящих доказательств, лишь тогда на этой основе выводится аксиома. Т.е. в математике вы заканчиваете аксиомой. "

Там не только Степанов, но и другие известные люди пинают ООП.

--

@danpetruk, Scala, Perl и C# чуть популярней, чем Ada c Prolog и все вместе не дотягивают до Python.

Comment: @avp самый известный рейтинг http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html

c# - 5 место
python - 8 место

Comment: @danpetruk, наверное самый. Только не надо забывать

    The ratings are based on the number of skilled engineers world-wide, courses and third party vendors. Popular search engines such as Google, Bing, Yahoo!, Wikipedia, Amazon, YouTube and Baidu are used to calculate the ratings. Observe that the TIOBE index is not about the best programming language or the language in which most lines of code have been written.

Но в любом случае лидируют императивные C/C++/Java/PHP/C#. Не думаете же Вы, что C# попал в эту компанию из-за наличия каких-то нетрадиционных примочек.

Comment: Похоже мои комментарии в этой ветке закончились.

Comment: @avp а что за примочки то? Порт под linux есть, фп и ооп встроены, что ещё надо?

Comment: @avp, аду называют одним из самых продуманных языков программирования за всю историю их существования, да и сейчас набирает популярность **Rust** от Мозиллы, который тоже собирается вобрать в себя всё самое лучшее из других языков.

Comment: @avp, писать систему на двух и более языках программирования мне кажется плохим стилем, так как это повышает требования к программистам. Да и необходимость этого довольно спорная уже было доказано, что можно написать программу любой сложности используя только условные операторы и циклы следовательно, велика вероятность того, что *любую* задачу можно решить *любым* языком программирования общего назначения. На каком - это уже дело вкуса.

Answer (score 2):

Если тебе хочется смешивать, есть такая тенденция как DSL. Ты можешь написать нужный функционал(чистый) специально под себя, вот Parus - отлично для констрейнтов, например, но можно сделать что угодно под себя. Небольшой доклад недавно слушал https://www.dropbox.com/s/nwe567bmj8lbqdr/TechTalk%2311%20-%20Demedetskiy%20-%20DSL%20creation.pdf?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

> **Вопрос:** есть ли такой замечательный язык, который бы совмещал обе парадигмы?

Вам понравился бы объектно-ориентированный язык [**Logtalk**](http://logtalk.org/).

Он является *надмножеством* языка **Prolog**.

В настоящее время он реализован как *препроцессор* с использованием
одной из версий **Prolog** как бэкенд-компилятора:

- **SWI Prolog**
- **XSB-Prolog**
- **YAP Prolog**
- **GNU Prolog**
- **JIProlog**
- **Sictus Prolog**

и другие, в т.ч. коммерческие версии **Prolog.**

Стоит взглянуть также на

http://plo.sourceforge.net/